# Conditions and Action disappeared from Civirules during upgrade

Tags: upgrade, civirules

I found that the actions weren't happening in Civirules and on investigation I found that all the conditions and actions were no longer there. I'm assuming that this happened during an upgrade where I went from CiviCRM 4.7 to 5.11.0 and also upgraded Civirules 2.1 to 2.5 at the same time. Maybe the problem was that I just installed the new version of Civirules rather than installing the old version on the upgraded site and and then upgrading. Things have obviously changed (for the better).

I couldn't find any release notes for new versions of Civirules. There is a note about having to re-input conditions and actions when upgrading to 2.x but I would interpret as being when you upgrade from 1.x.

Anyway, I've sported this out by re-inputting the conditions and actions and find that some of the things that didn't work for me before now do, so it was worth the hassle. I also upgraded to 2.7 before doing this.

So only real question is where are release notes for Civirules and otherwise it is hopefully useful information for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are release notes they will be on Gitlab and in the changelog in the extension, but that was a fairly recent improvement.
I have seen the problem you had, that is why the note is there. And AFAIK it applies for any version earlier than 2.2

Comment: Yes there is a note in https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules about this and the CHANGELOG linked from there has the release notes. Thanks,